# Caught NSInternalInconsistencyException request for rect at invalid indexPath

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest

The following line crashes the program:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ItemCell", forIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)) as! ItemCell
```

The console log shows the following error:

```
"caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException", "request for rect at invalid index path (<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0})"
```

Here is a bullet point list of things I've checked:

- Correct Storyboard ID is listed in the identity inspector
- Correct custom class is listed in the identity inspector
- Attributes inspector has "ItemCell" in the Table View Cell identifier field

Here is the full code:

```
import XCTest
@testable import ToDo

class ItemCellTests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testSUT_HasNameLabel(){

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ItemListViewController") as! ItemListViewController

        _=controller.view

        let tableView = controller.tableView
        tableView.dataSource = FakeDataSource()

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ItemCell", forIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)) as! ItemCell


        XCTAssertNotNil(cell.titleLabel)
    }
}


extension ItemCellTests{
    class FakeDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the ItemCell.swift code:

```
import UIKit

class ItemCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!


    func configCellWithItem(item: ToDoItem){

    }
}
```

All properties that are tied to the storyboard are connected.  What is being overlooked?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like this code is from my book. That's a known error in the book. Change the test method to the following:

```
func testSUT_HasNameLabel(){

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ItemListViewController") as! ItemListViewController

    _=controller.view

    let tableView = controller.tableView
    let dataProvider = FakeDataSource()
    tableView.dataSource = dataProvider

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ItemCell", forIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)) as! ItemCell

    XCTAssertNotNil(cell.titleLabel)
}
```

Then, when you later refactor that code to put the setup into the `setUp` method, add a property `let dataProvider = FakeDataSource()` to the test case and set it to the data source of the table view (`tableView.dataSource = dataProvider`) in `setUp`.

Comment: Glad to have your answer but what's the take away from this?

Comment: The reason the version from the book didn't work is, the `dataSource` of the `tableView` is a weak reference. When you set it with an new instance, it is freed immediately. So you need a local variable for that object. I didn't see that when I wrote the book, because I tested the code on an iPhone 4s simulator and there it doesn't crash. I don't know why.

Comment: @dasdom the reason makes sense, but the error message doesn't. How did you find the source of the problem? Any evidence that let you understand?

Comment: @Jean-DenisMuys I added break points and run through it using the debugger.

Comment: For the refactoring, I added this to the class:  var dataProvider: UITableViewDataSource!
That way, there is no duplicated code in test cases.

Answer (score 2):

A solution that I found so far was by changing the initial problem-child function which was:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ItemCell", forIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)) as! ItemCell
```

By changing to the following for the tests to pass:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ItemCell") as! ItemCell
```

Comment: I'm following the same book and stuck on same problem. Though this solves the problem, what's the take away from this?

Comment: I'm the author of the book. Please see my answer.